# Extending Comparable in a generic class

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I have a problem. I need a class to store two values, one called `key` and one called `value`. The class can store the objects, return `value` and allow comparison between two objects by comparing the key value.

```
public class Entry <K,V> implements Comparable<Entry<K,V>> 
{
    private K key;
    private V value;

    public Entry(K key,V value)
    {
        this.key=key;
        this.value=value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value)
    {
        this.value=value;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "key= "+key+" value=" +value;
    }
}
```

He is now asking me to add the `Comparable` method. I am allowed to use `equalsTo(Object)` as well. How can I implement `Comparable`? I tried

```
public Comparable(k key)
{
    if (this.k < k)
        return -1; 

    if (this.k > k)
        return 1;

    else return 0;
}
```

but I got an error saying that I am not allowed to use `>` or `<`.

Comment: your method should be called compareTo. You should delegate the comparison to the K class, probably by making it Comparable itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers here seem to be very confused as to generics and the `Comparable` `interface`.

Here is some code that will compile:

```
public class Entry<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Comparable<Entry<K, V>> {

    private final K key;
    private V value;

    public Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }   

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entry<K, V> other) {
        return key.compareTo(other.key);
    }
}
```

So you force the type of your key to also extend `Comparable` to itself; you then use its `compareTo` method to compare your `Entry` to the other `Entry` based on the keys.

Comment: This one kind of worked but when i try to Compare something i actually have an exception..i tryed for (int i=0; i<strArr.length;i++)
  {
  if (entryArr[i].compareTo("L") == 0)
   System.out.println(entryArr[i].toString());
  } and it says that Compare to should be parametrized

Comment: This `entryArr[i].compareTo("L")` looks like you are trying to compare an `Entry<String, V>` to a `String`? This won't work - you need to do `entryArr[i].getKey().compareTo("L")`.